# Details of the "New Yale" sparse matrix format?

Tags: data-structures, fortran, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

There's some Netlib code written in Fortran which performs transposes and multiplication on sparse matrices. The library works with Bank-Smith (sort of), "old Yale", and "new Yale" formats.

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find much detail on "new Yale." I implemented what I think matches the description [given in the paper](http://www.mgnet.org/~douglas/Preprints/pub0034.pdf), and I can get and set entries appropriately.

But the results are not correct, leading me to wonder if I've implemented something which matches the description in the paper but is not what the Fortran code expects.

So a couple of questions:

**Should row lengths include diagonal entries?** e.g., if you have `M=[1,1;0,1]`, it seems that it should look like this:

```
IJA = [3,4,4,1]
A   = [1,1,X,1] // where X=NULL
```

It seems that if diagonal entries are included in row lengths, you'd get something like this:

```
IJA = [3,5,6,1]
A   = [1,1,X,1]
```

That doesn't make much sense because `IJA[2]=6` should be the size of the IJA/A arrays, but it *is* what the paper seems to say.

**Should the matrices use 1-based indexing?**

It is Fortran code after all. Perhaps instead my IJA and A should look like this:

```
IJA = [4,5,5,2]
A   = [1,1,X,1] // still X=NULL
```

**Is there anything else I'm missing?**

Yes, that's vague, but I throw that out there in case someone who has messed with this code before would like to volunteer any additional information. Anyone else can feel free to ignore this last question.

I know these questions may seem rather trivial, but I thought perhaps some Fortran folks could provide me with some insight. I'm not used to thinking in a one-based system, and though I've converted the code to C using `f2c`, it's still written like Fortran.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, first of all, the reference given in [the SMMP paper](http://www.mgnet.org/~douglas/Preprints/pub0034.pdf) is possibly not the correct one. I [checked it out](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/42324977/The%20%28New%29%20Yale%20Sparse%20Matrix%20Package.pdf) (the ref) from the library last night. It appears to give the "old Yale" format. It does mention, on pp. 49-50, that the diagonal can be separated out from the rest of the matrix -- but doesn't so much as mention an IJA vector.

I was able to find the format described in the 1992 edition of [*Numerical Recipes in C*](http://apps.nrbook.com/c/index.html) on pp. 78-79.

Of course, there is no guarantee that this is the format accepted by the SMMP library from Netlib.

*NR* seems to have IA giving positions relative to IJA, not relative to JA. The last position in the IA portion gives not the size of the IJA and A vectors, but `size-1`, because the vectors are indexed starting at 1 (per Fortran standard).

Row lengths do not include non-zero diagonal entries.

Answer (score 3):

I can't see how you deduced those vectors from that paper.  First the Old Yale format:

```
M = [7,16;0,-12]
```

Then, `A` contains all non-zero values of M in row-form:
    A = [7,16,-12]

and `IA` stores the position in `A` of the first elements of each row, and `JA` stores the column indices of all the values in `A`:

```
IA = [1,3,4]
JA = [1,2,2]
```

New format: `A` has diagonal values first, a zero and then the remaining non-zero elements (I have put `|` to clarify the seperation between diagonal and non-diagonal) :

```
A = [7,-12,0 | 16]
```

`IA` and `JA` are combined in `IJA`, but as far as I can tell from the paper you need to take into account the new ordering of A (I have put `|` to clarify the seperation between `IA` and `JA`):

```
IJA = [1,2,3 | 2]
```

So, applied to your case `M = [1,1;0,1]`, I get

```
A   = [1,1,0 | 1]
IJA = [1,2,3 | 2]
```

first element of the first row is the first in `A` and the first element of the second row is the second in `A`, then I put `3` since they say the length of a row is determined by `IA(I)-IA(I+1)`, so I make sure the difference is `1`.  Then the column indices of the non-zero non-diagonal elements follow, and that is `2`.

Comment: Interesting. You interpreted the description in the paper completely differently than I. It seems like the largest difference is whether IA positions should be relative to JA or relative to IJA.

I did some more research in the library last night, so I'm going to post what I found as a separate answer and turn this into a Wiki, I think.